# How to check if at least n% of a list contains certain value x?

Tags: c#, list, count, contains, percentage

Is there any existing simple method in C# where I can check if a list contains at least n% of a certain value.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
if ( myList.Contains(5).percentage(75) )
{
  /*do something*/
}
```

Comment: There is no built-in method, as far as I'm aware. I'd use the LINQ `Count` method and work out the percentage myself.

Comment: I think you've significantly overestimated how common such a check would be, to expect there to be a framework method.

Comment: If you want to use LINQ like syntax, I suggest you just write your own extension method for your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking to count the items with a value of 5 and this amount exceeds 75% of the number of items in the list:

```
if ( myList.Where(value => value == 5).Count() >= myList.Count * 75 / 100 )
{
}
```

Or also:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var myList = new List<int>();

int valueToCheck = 5;

double percentTrigger = 0.75;
int countTrigger = (int)Math.Round(myList.Count * percentTrigger);

if ( myList.Count(value => value == valueToCheck) >= countTrigger )
{
}
```

The use of Round makes it possible to refine the test condition according to the percentage.

[Enumerable.Count Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count)

[Percentage calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561374/percentage-calculation)

---

As suggested by @cmos we can create an extension medthod to refactor that:

```
static public class EnumerableHelper
{
  static public bool IsCountReached(this IEnumerable<int> collection, int value, int percent)
  {
    int countTrigger = (int)Math.Round((double)collection.Count() * percent / 100);
    return collection.Count(item => item == value) >= countTrigger;
  }
}
```

*Usage*

```
if ( myList.IsCountReached(5, 75) )
{
}
```

From the long awaited [Preview Features in .NET 6 – Generic Math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/):

```
static public class EnumerableHelper
{
  static public bool IsCountReached<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T value, int percent)
  where T : INumber<T>
  {
    int countTrigger = (int)Math.Round((double)collection.Count() * percent / 100);
    return collection.Count(item => item == value) >= countTrigger;
  }
}
```

Comment: this would be expensive because it needs to iterate through all elements, even though you can early break out if the result is satisfied

Comment: @phuclv Indeed, the use of a handmade loop and a break will be more optimized, but Count is the closest available .NET API to what the OP requests.